# Ggridgain cluster crashes after JVM error

Tags: gridgain

I am getting below error on Gridgain cluster and cluster is not coming up.

Any idea?

```
Thread [name="main", id=1, state=WAITING, blockCnt=1, waitCnt=16]
    Lock [object=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync@5d0db03c, ownerName=null, ownerId=-1]
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
        at o.a.i.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:323)


[09:48:08,150][WARNING][client-connector-#82][CacheDiagnosticManager] Page locks dump:

[09:48:08,150][SEVERE][client-connector-#82][] JVM will be halted immediately due to the failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=CRITICAL_ERROR, err=class o.a.i.i.processors.cache.persistence.StorageException: Failed to initialize partition file: /database/ignite/ignite_data/db/myIgnite_Node1/cache-customerAddressCache/part-728.bin]]
```

Comment: Please share the complete log file, there has to be more information related to the error.

Comment: I would suggest try to increase soft/hard ulimit for the system and user that runs GridGain node. Please check the current limit and number of files that are currently existing in the node persistent directory (especially the number of partition files in installation_path/work/db).